# IOS Mapview set region crashing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

My application is crashing self.mapView.setRegion method when I'm trying to set the region for the map view.

I will get the location details from API like longitude, latitude, accuracy.

```
 {
          "latitude": -96.790127,
          "longitude": 32.782054,
          "bearing": 233,
          "altitude": 23423,
          "accuracy": 20
 }
```

I want to show the pin for the longitude and latitude

[image: Crash Xcode Swift code Image.]

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var location : ICDLocationModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        location = SCFileManager.readJsonFile(file: "location") as ICDLocationModel
        self.determineCurrentLocation()

        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)

        //create location
        print("Location : \(location) \n\n ")

        let mapCenter   = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location!.latitude!, location!.longitude!)
        print("mapCenter : \(mapCenter) \n\n ")

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCenter, span: span)
        print("region : \(region) \n\n ")

        //set map view to specified locaiton
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }

}
```

Comment: We can't answer your question as-is. You should add the code you use, where it crashses and so on.

Comment: The mapView should not be nil, @Krunal, as the connection from IB seems to be there (according to the screenshot).

Comment: pprint mapview <MKMapView: 0x10a038e00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c02237a0>>
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: log the values of lat long and mapCenter and mapReigon. The crash is due to nil value

Comment: I got the issue, The longitude and latitude is invalied

Comment: What does your crash message say ?

Comment: Could you share the repo where the code is? I'd be more than happy to have a look at it (I have worked a LOT with maps in the past)